# DocuSign API - Reset/Unlock RecipientAuthenticationStatus

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API to electronically sign documents within my app. I'm using the access code authentication feature, for some additional security; however, I am trying to 'Unlock'  a signer (via the API) that has input the wrong access code too many times, without voided and creating a new envelope, or using the DocuSign Admin interface.

I don't care if I have to resend the initial email, I just want to be able to conserve my client's total envelope count. It's also important (if there are multiple signers) that I don't force one signer to have to sign multiple times, if they completed their signatures prior to signer2's authentication error.

I have attempted a POST to:

```
 /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?resend_envelope=true
```

I have also sought a solution using the docusign-java-client:

```
Recipients recipients = envelopesApi.listRecipients(accountId, envelopeId);
List<Signer> signers = recipients.getSigners(); 

for (Signer signer : signers) {
    signer.setRecipientAuthenticationStatus(null);  
}
```

I still get the below response

```
"recipientAuthenticationStatus": {
    "accessCodeResult": {
      "status": "Failed",
      "eventTimestamp": "2018-01-15T23:49:15.8600000Z"
 }
```

I'm able to "Resend" via the DocuSign admin GUI, and everything works as expected...

Is there any way that I'm able "reset/unlock" this authentication feature programatically, through the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below `PUT` endpoint

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/<envelopeId>?resend_envelope=true
```

Body as:

```
{
}
```

This should send another email to the signer who failed the authentication, and that user will again get option to enter the access code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to delete and then re-add the recipient (signer). That makes the signer become a new recipient.

However, doing so means you'll need to re-create everything about the signer: their document tabs/fields, etc.

I can't imagine that it is less expensive to simply void/resend the envelope than to spend a developer's time to work on this issue.

If this scenario is occurring a lot, then perhaps think about providing better training to your signers with respect to using the access code feature.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was able to answer my question. As far as the "less expensive" bit, I completely agree; however as a developer, I don't have the liberty to make that decision. I just try to develop the most effective and efficient way I see possible, even if that means spending a dollar to save pennies over an extended period of time. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help. Thank you for using DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation found [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm?Highlight=resend_envelope)

I must include the json or xml with the request (if the authentication method failed). I assumed incorrectly that if there was only one recipient, then I would NOT have to specify. If you just want to resend the envelope, you don't need to include and signer data.

Such as:

```
{"signers" :
    [{"email":"testEmail@gmail.com",
      "name":"FirstName LastName",
      "recipientId":"1"
     }]
 }
```

You should then get something like the below response:

```
{"recipientUpdateResults": 
   [{
      "recipientId": "1",
      "errorDetails": 
       {
         "errorCode": "SUCCESS",
         "message": ""
       }
   }]
 }
```